# Inequality on non-negative reals

Tags: inequality, polynomials, factoring, fractions, tangent-line-method

For non-negative $x,y,z$ satisfy $\frac{1}{2x^2+1}+\frac{1}{2y^2+1}+\frac{1}{2z^2+1}=1$ then show that $x^2+y^2+z^2+6\geq 3(x+y+z)$

Idea how to handle the constraint? I'm unaware .

Comment: As a side observation, the assumption $x,y,z\ge0$ should not be strictly necessary: if that implication holds for non-negative reals, then it holds for all reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true for all reals.

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2-3x+2)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^2-3x+2-\frac{9}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2x^2+1}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(x-1)^2(2x-1)^2}{2(2x^2+1)}\geq0$.

Done!

Comment: Magic! How did you come up with this?

Comment: @marty cohen $x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$ and $x-2=-1$ for $x=1$. In another hand, $\frac{1}{2x^2+1}-\frac{1}{3}=-\frac{2(x-1)(x+1)}{3(2x^2+1)}$ and $-\frac{2(x+1)}{3(2x^2+1)}=-\frac{4}{9}$ for $x=1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg truly magical is your solution.